# Como serializar uma exception com closure

Tags: php, exceção, serialização, closures

Estou tentando serializar as exceptions geradas por erros  para gravar um log com todas as informações, mas o problema é que algumas exceptions podem vir com um `closure` dentro do *trace* e disparam a mensagem abaixo:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'

Se eu escrever um arquivo usando o objeto `$exception` ele grava usando o método mágico `__toString`. Queria gravar a *exception* completa, por isso o uso do `serialize / unserialize`.

Pelo que vi, um objeto `closure` não pode ser serializado, então, como posso fazer para remover do *trace* da exception e serializa-la? Meu último desejo é usar `OB*` para isso.

Answer (score 7):

Caso não seja problema, você pode incluir um package no seu projeto para possibilitar a serialização de `Clousures`.

Lembro que o Laravel 4 utiliza esse mesmo package para o mesmo problema:

https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure

Retirado do leia me do Super Closure:

> Have you ever seen this?
>
> ```
> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'
> ```
>
> It's true! If you try to serialize a Closure, PHP will throw an
>   exception and tell you that it is not allowed. But even though it is
>   not "allowed" by PHP, the Super Closure library
>   (jeremeamia/superclosure on Packagist) makes it possible.

Tradução livre:

> Por acaso você já viu isso?
>
> ```
> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed'
> ```
>
> Sim, é verdade! Caso você tente serializar um Closure, o PHP irá arremessar
>   uma exceção informando que não é possível. Porém mesmo que isso
>   não seja "permitido" pelo PHP, a biblioteca Super Closure
>   (jeremeamia/superclosure no Packagist) torna isso possível.

Comment: O problema maior é esse *__construct* desse pack que recebe um tipo *Closure*, mas nem sempre eu terei ele dentro do trace da exception. Os closures são parte da composição da view, não são importantes como log.

Comment: @PapaCharlie então na verdade você quer ignorar os *Closures* na hora de serializar?

Comment: No momento faço um loop nos *traces* para remover o índice *args*. Os *closures* são irrelevantes no meu caso, por isso achei mais simples descartá-los da exception.